# Passwordless sftp closing connection without transferring files

Tags: sftp

I'm trying to transfer the files with passwordless sftp. It was working till last week and using the same keys, I was able to transfer the files from a different server. But, this one is closing connection immediately after entering the command- sftp -v -oIdentityFile=/home/n123456/.ssh/id_rsa_ability abc@xyz.com. It is authenticating using the public key. PFB the verbose log.

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to abc@xyz port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /home/n123456/.ssh/id_rsa_ability type 1
debug1: identity file /home/n123456/.ssh/id_rsa_ability-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug1: kex: ecdh-sha2-nistp256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: ecdh-sha2-nistp256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxx
debug1: Host 'abc@xyz' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server not found in Kerberos database

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/n123456/.ssh/id_rsa_ability
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to xyz (xxxxxxx:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 3440, received 3072 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 37158.3, received 33183.2
debug1: Exit status 1
Connection closed
```

Comment: What happens when you ssh into it?

Answer (score 1):

The server failed to initialize the SFTP subsystem.

In general, there's not much you can do about it. Contact the server administrator to get the server fixed.

This most probably has nothing to do with your keys.